# What is the name of the OS X command that generates ranges of values?

Tags: macos, terminal

I came across an article some time ago that discussed obscure OS X terminal commands.

One of the commands generated a range of characters using up to three values, from memory it went something like this:

```
<command> a z
```

This would generate a range of characters from a to z.

Similarly, you could use something like this to generate a incrementing series by a certain value:

```
<command> 0 100 10
```

Would generate values from 0 to 100 and increment the value by 10 each time.

Does anyone know of the command I'm talking about? I finally found a good use for it and now I can't remember the name of the damn command! :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I was thinking of was `seq`

EXAMPLES

```
# seq 1 3
1
2
3

# seq 3 1
3
2
1

# seq -w 0 .05 .1
0.00
0.05
0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing I can think of is a for loop in bash, such as this (scroll down to examples)
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

I'm pretty sure there's no command that does this specifically

#### Edit

You can actually do this on the command line, for example

```
echo {1..20}
```